# How to delete row from Ruby Sequel table based on two conditions

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a table (Device) that I am using Ruby to access.  I want to delete a row if it fulfills these two conditions:

```
{:user_id => params[:user_id]}
```

and

```
{:reg_token => params[:reg_token]}
```

However, I'm not sure if I know how to use `AND` correctly.  I am trying to follow this guide:

http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/dataset_filtering_rdoc.html

```
if Device.where{Sequel.&({:user_id => params[:user_id]}, {:reg_token => params[:reg_token]})}.count > 0
    # device = Device.where((:user_id => params[:user_id]) & (:reg_token => params[:reg_token])).delete
    device = Device.where{Sequel.&({:user_id => params[:user_id]}, {:reg_token => params[:reg_token]})}.delete
end
```

Comment: Read the documentation about having Sequel show you the SQL it will emit. Typically you can put `.sql` at the end of the query but there are other ways too. Then compare that output to what the DBM documentation says an `AND` query should look like.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just chain the `where` clauses:

```
devices = Device.where(user_id: params[:user_id]).where(reg_token: params[:reg_token])
devices.delete_all
```

Comment: thanks, that worked.  I had to use devices.delete instead of delete_all

Comment: It is not even necessary to chain them. You can use a single where with the hash syntax: `devices = Device.where(user_id: params[:user_id], reg_token: params[:reg_token])`